# Shortcut to connection speed setting

Tags: lumia, 8.1, settings, cellular-data

In previous Windows Phone versions the highest connection speed option (2G/3G/4G) was on the same screen as "Data connection on/off" option.

Now it isn't any more and I would like to know if it is possible to make direct shortcut from the home screen to this setting?

[image: mobile+sim]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try **Cellular Data** from **Microsoft** but available only in **US**. You can get it by changing your region to US. You can have it from [Windows Phone Site](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/cellular-data/cb9ca504-e5dc-4055-9f09-488399e3b950)

Answer (score 3):

**No**, it's not possible to create a shortcut to that screen (at this time).

The Mobile+SIM screen was updated in Windows Phone 8.1 to accommodate dual-sim phones. The details for each SIM now have their own separate page.